# Omit section if following section is null/blank

Tags: crystal-reports, sections

The *Articles* table contains the details of my articles, and another table *Stores* contains the movements of the items in my various stores. My report summarizes and organizes the items in a warehouse passed as an initial parameter.

Here is an example of the *Stores* table:

```
StoreCode  ArticleCode  ArticleCategory  NrID  Cont  Pcs  Kgs  [...]
1120       MEC          CAT01            B1801  1    +30  300 
1120       MEC          CAT02            B1801  1    +80  800 
1120       MEC          CAT02            B1801  1    -20  200 
1120       MEC          CAT03            B1801  1    +50  500 
1120       MEC          CAT03            B1801  1    -50  500 
1120       MEC          CAT04            B1801  1    +90  900 
1120       MEC          CAT04            B1802  1    +10  100 
1120       MEC          CAT04            B1802  1    -5   50</pre>
```

The report is structured as follows:

```
Header 1: group by ArticleCode
    Just a formula field that shows the full name of the article based on the code read from the database
Header 2: group by CatArt
    empty
Header 3: groups by NrID
    empty
Header 4: groups by Cont
    empty
Details
    empty
Footer 4: 
    sum the pieces and the kilos
Footer 3: 
    empty
Footer 2: 
    empty
Footer 1: 
    empty
```

Results:

```
HS1: "Article source MEC of category 01"
FS4: MEC CAT01 30 pcs x 300 kg
HS1: "Article source MEC of category 02"
FS4: MEC CAT02 60 pcs x 600 kg
HS1: "Article source MEC of category 03"
FS4:
HS1: "Article source MEC of category 04"
FS4: MEC CAT04 95 pcs x 950 kg
```

As you can see from the *FS4*, the article `MEC CAT03` has not been printed because it has 0 pieces but the description in the *HS1* instead is printed even if there aren't the respective lines.

How can I omit the printing of the section *HS1* if the underlying *FS4* is in turn omitted (via an `If Pcs <= 0`)?

I tried to insert an omission formula in *HS1* like below, but it omits all the `HS1`:

```
If Sum ({FS4.Pcs}) <= 0 Then
    True;
```

Comment: Your final formula is redundant. You can achieve the same thing with just `Sum ({FS4.Pcs}) <= 0` - No need for `If`, `Then`, or `True`

Comment: Do you have the entry if Zero pieces or its just a `null`?

Comment: I can handle both, but the main problem is that the *HS1* section fails to omit on the basis of parameters that are in the section below *FS4* and that have not yet been calculated. This is my problem.